# How do I change VS Code Settings to use JetBrains Mono Font

Tags: visual-studio-code, fonts, jetbrains-font

I've downloaded and installed the JetBrains Mono font https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/

I'm trying to set VS Code to use it.

I've added the following lines to my settings.json file:

```
    // Set the font
    "editor.fontFamily": "Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace", // Copied from current settings
    // Turn on font ligatures
    "editor.fontLigatures": true, // Override default value of false
```

My question is: what do I need to put in the `editor.fontFamily` section to get JetBrains to be used?

I've tried `"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains, Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace"`
without success.

Comment: I had to also restart Visual Studio Code for the change to take place.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Open the VSCode Settings (Code -> Preferences -> Settings), then add to the end of the User Settings JSON file:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",
  "editor.fontSize": 13,
  "editor.fontLigatures": true
```

Comment: I followed a few advices on here and the font changed but the color scheme of the font is still the VSCode default.

Comment: The font should be in single quotes like so "editor.fontFamily": "'JetBrains Mono'"

Answer (score 42):

Building on what @Grekkq and @Gyliph provided, this is how my settings look:

```
    // Set the font
    "editor.fontFamily": "'JetBrains Mono', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace",
    // Set the font size
    "editor.fontSize": 13,
    // Turn on font ligatures
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    // Set letter spacing
    "editor.letterSpacing": 0.4,
    // Enable smooth scrolling in the editor
    "editor.smoothScrolling": true,
```

The trick to adding JetBrains Mono to the current list of font families was to wrap `'JetBrains Mono'` in single quotes (since there is a space in the font name).

Comment: Q: If I wanted to use the **Medium** or **Bold** version of the installed font how do I specify that?

Comment: @MMJ You can use "editor.fontWeight": "bold". For intermediate weights you can also specify numbers, e.g., "editor.fontWeight": "300". The code completion shows all available options.

Answer (score 12):

Just this will be enough

```
"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono"
```

And if u want ligatures as well

```
"editor.fontLigatures": true
```

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is:

- open settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>
- choose Text Editor -> Font
- add **'JetBrains Mono'** to the font family

Also from there you can change font weight and size, then restart your VS Code to see the change

[image]

Or in **settings.json** file. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>, search for settings.json, and then add those lines:

```
  "editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono", // Font Family
  "editor.fontSize": 11.3, // Font Size
  "editor.fontWeight": "bold", // Font Weight
  "editor.fontLigatures": true, // Font ligatures
```

Answer (score 7):

I struggled to change fonts in VS Code, but now it's working every time I want to change it. In order to change the font, please follow these instructions:

1. Download the font
2. Click on the ttl file you just downloaded and click on install
3. CLOSE VS CODE AND RE OPEN IT.
4. Go into VS Code and change the font you want; e.g., JetBrains Mono

The trick is to CLOSE & RE OPEN VS CODE

#THANKS TO PINAKI FOR THE SOLUTION

Comment: No need to restart the computer, just close the VS code and then open again.

Answer (score 5):

For people trying to follow along and are noob like me: YOU NEED TO DOWNLOAD THE FONT FIRST!

https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/

Then unpack, select all of them, right-click any of them and choose INSTALL.

In VS Code settings.json (search for font in settings and you will see this) write:

`"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",` <-- Don't forget this comma

RESTART VSCODE

Enjoy.

Answer (score 4):

First, you will enter your preferences -> settings -> Text Editor -> Font

And then you can click and edit your settings.json there

[How to find font settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObNGY.png)

Then, you can edit your settings there, like you can see below. Here is what my font settings looks like (including a visual demo of JetBrains in it!):

[My settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NT6Er.png)

Answer (score 3):

You maybe notice that the **default weight isn't right**, so to change to be the same in e.g. PyCharm:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrainsMonoRoman-Light",
```

I got this from going to user installed fonts -> the info tab on the top -> PostScript name

Comment: Thank you! For me the name was "JetBrainsMono-Regular_Light". Font by going into the MacOS Font Book app, looking up JetBrains Mono, selecting "Light" from the drop down, pressing the "(i)" icon, and clicking on "Identifiers"

Answer (score 2):

I installed both `Twilio Mono Sans` (OTF ) and `JetBrains Mono`, but it wasn't working. I needed to **restart** my **Windows** 11 machine, then it worked fine.

Make sure to install the font first, then with `Ctrl + shift + P` open the VSCode User Settings (JSON), finally add:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono",
"editor.fontSize": 13,
"editor.fontLigatures": true
```

and if you are using Windows and it didn't work right away, even reopening/reloading VSCode, try restarting yout PC.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to obtain almost identical visual feel by downloading and installing the [JetBrains font](https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mono/) (as for the [answer by plotsklapps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70770621/5422162)), then using these settings:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "JetBrains Mono Light",
"editor.fontSize": 13,
"editor.fontLigatures": false,
"editor.letterSpacing": 0.3,
"editor.lineHeight": 1.7,
```

---

To complement the answer, I am using the [Darkula theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rokoroku.vscode-theme-darcula) from the Marketplace modified with these settings:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Darcula]": {
        "editor.foreground": "#a9b7c6",
        "editor.background": "#1E1F22",
        "editorGutter.background": "#1E1F22",
        "editorLineNumber.foreground": "#4e5157",
        "editorLineNumber.activeForeground": "#9da0a8",
        "editor.selectionBackground": "#214283",
        "editor.wordHighlightBackground": "#344134",
        "editor.findMatchBackground": "#214283",
        "editor.findMatchBorder": "#214283",
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBackground": "#32593D",
        "editor.findMatchHighlightBorder": "#3C704B"
    }
},
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqWxx.png) a preview of the final result.